# Clarification on Construction of Tensor Product (Atiyah-Macdonald)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For context: $M, N, P$ are $A$-modules, $C = A^{(M \times N)}$ is the free $A$-module on the cartesian product $M \times N$, $D$ is the submodule generated by all elements of the form $(x + x^{'}, y) - (x,y) - (x^{'}, y), (x, y + y^{'}) - (x, y) - (x, y^{'}), (ax,y) - a(x,y), (x,ay) - a(x,y)$.

From page 25,

"Any map $f: M \times N \rightarrow P$ extends by linearity to an $A$-module homomorphism $\bar{f}: C \rightarrow P$"

My question is how is this map $\bar{f}$ defined?  I would imagine that for any element in the direct sum $C$ we would sum the elements as elements of $M \times N$ and then apply the map $f$, but this doesn't exactly sound right.  Is there a more obvious way of extending this map by linearity?

Comment: For your question $D$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That such an extension exists is basically the definition of $C$ being the free $A$-module over $M \times N$. Of course, this is not a very helpful thing to say so let's be explicit.

For ease of notation, let me write $S = M \times N$, so $C = A^{(S)}$.

An element of $A^{(S)}$ is a formal sum $\sum_{s \in S} a_s s$ where all but finitely many $a_s$ are zero. If you prefer something more concrete, elements of $A^{(S)}$ are functions $a: S \longrightarrow A$ with finite support. That is, for all but finitely many $s \in S$, $a(s) = 0$. Addition and scalar multiplication can be defined on these functions on each component. We can also define these operations on the representation $\sum_{s \in S} a_s s$ as follows:

$$
\sum_{s \in S} a_s s + \sum_{s \in S} b_s s = \sum_{s \in S} (a_s + b_s) s
$$
$$
a\left(\sum_{s \in S} a_s s \right) = \sum_{s \in S} (a a_s) s
$$

Now, how do we define such an extension $\widetilde f$ given $f: S \longrightarrow P$? Well we only know how to act on $f$, so how do we act on a formal sum $\sum_{s \in S} a_s s$? Let's apply formal reasoning. If we had such a map $\widetilde f$, then as it's an $A$ module homomorphism we'd have to have

$$
\widetilde f\left(\sum_{s \in S} a_s s\right) = \sum_{s \in S} \widetilde f(a_s s) = \sum_{s \in S} a_s \widetilde f(s)
$$
and if $\widetilde f$ is to extend $f$, then $\widetilde f(s) = f(s)$ for $s \in S$.

So we are led to take this as our *definition* of $\widetilde f$:

$$
\widetilde f\left(\sum_{s \in S} a_s s\right) := \sum_{s \in S} a_s f(s)
$$

Now, you can check that $\widetilde f$ is a well defined $A$ module homomorphism extending $f$.